# Using reflection on another java process

Tags: java, reflection

Basically I have another java process, for simplicity sake I will call it Test.jar. I have another program, lets call it Program.jar. My goal is to be able to run Test.jar on my computer, then inside of Program.jar I want to be able to find and detect the correct process for Test.jar, if Test.jar isn't running or not found it will just display some sort of message to start Test.jar, and be able to manipulate it with reflection or something similar. Basically hook into a different java process.

Is this possible? Does anyone know any resources with info on it? Thanks

Okay, so about the post on the XY problem. I will make it a bit more clear.

I have a client that requires authentication to get into it. Once it is logged in, the client is constantly running on a computer and what I need to do is create a third party program that will hook into the client and tell it to connect to a certain host (possibly by using a method that is already in the client) without modifying the source code of the client itself.

Comment: Just one word - **why**?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Why not just look for the running process, then start it if it's not there... Once it's started you can communicate with sockets, or other communication, no need for reflection.

Comment: It may answer your question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839815/rmi-java-reflection

Comment: @home Basically I am trying to get a program that is already running to do something without user input and without modifying that program

Comment: This sounds like a use-case for illegitimate modification of a program you've not written since you "don't want to" modify Test.jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process cannot "call" methods of other process. Both processes are absolutely separated by operating system.

Processes can talk via network even if they are running on the same computer. You can implement your own protocol and send messages over TCP while one of the processes (seems your Test) will be a server and other is a client. You can however simplify your task by using higher level tools, for example RMI. However it seems that you need even more higher level API, for example JMX.

So, if you described all your requirements I'd recommend you JMX.

But if there are other requirements please describe them. I'd recommend you to describe here your task as it is defined by product management. Your Program.jar and Test.jar are part of your architecture that probably is not the best choice, so I believe that community can help you to make better design if you describe what you really need.

Good luck.